# how do I generate the .bin (executable) when creating a C++ Makefile project in eclipse (ubuntu)?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

I've seen answers near the problem I have but anyone actually useful. I've just created a C++ Makefile project in eclipse. I've added just a main.cpp file with some little code inside and created by hand the make file that is as follows:

```
LINK_TARGET = helloworld

OBJS = \
    main.o

REBUILDABLES = $(OBJS) $(LINK_TARGET)

clean :
    rm -f $(REBUILDABLES)
    @echo Clean done

all : $(LINK_TARGET)
    @echo All done

$(LINK_TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    g++ -g -o $@ $^

%.o : %.cpp
    g++ -g -o $@ -c $<
```

Everything Compiles fine and I can see that two files are generated in the Project Explorer Pane. Is generated main.o and the file **helloworld** is created but is just a file without extension and I think this is the file that is supposed to be the bin. But it is not, is just a file. When I try to debug the code in the **debug as** options there is no executable file to debug.

Do I have to do something extra to get the .bin generated? I'm doing all this in ubuntu.

Regards.

Comment: "no executable file to debug" what do you mean by this? what exactly happens when u click on "run"

Comment: Since I've just finished the main.cpp and makefile files addition, I right-click on the project in the project explorer pane and select "Debug as..." and then "Debug Configurations". Here I double-click the "C/C++ Application" and in the main tab there is no c/c++ application listed in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In linux executables dont have extensions typically. Indeed extensions as a whole are largely optional. You should be able to do `./helloworld` in the `bin` folder to run your exe

Answer (score 0):

I see what happened.

This file generated, the one I thought didn't have extension, is effectively the executable. What I just had to do is that when choosing "Debug as..." is just click "Browse..." button and select this "helloworld" in my application root folder. Actually in the application selection window the file can bee seen as an executable.

So after selecting it, the "Debug" button at the bottom of the "Debug configurations" dialog gets enabled and it allows me to debug as well as run the application.